# Subtracting using while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to subtract from a variable called `h` that is set to `1000` using another variable `x` which is set to get a random number from `3` to `65` using a `while` loop and it's giving me the same number over and over again not subtracting anything.

```
import random

x = random.randrange(3, 65)
h = 1000

while True:
    h > x
    print(h - x)
    if x > h:
        break

print('complete')
```

Comment: You don't reseed the random number in the while loop. So why would it be different? You always subtract **the same** `x` from `h`.

Comment: 1. You're picking a random number *outside* the loop; and 2. You only *show* the result of the subtraction, it doesn't actually change anything. Also `h > x` won't do anything. Did you think about this at all?!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the random number inside the loop and update h, otherwise the loop will not end because h is always greater than x:

```
import random
h = 1000
x = random.randrange(3, 65)

while h>x:
    x = random.randrange(3, 65)
    h -= x
    print h
print "complete"
```

If you want to substract always the same random number in the loop, just remove the x-assignment from the loop.

Comment: Note you can use *"augmented assignment"* - `h -= x` is shorthand for `h = h - x`. Also `x` doesn't exist at first, so you'll get a `NameError`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things here:

1. you do not assign the subtraction result to `h` again
2. you do not seed your random generator, it will give you the same number every run
3. your test should be the first thing in the loop, otherwise `h` may get negative
4. depending on what you want; `x = random.randrange(3, 65)` needs to be in the loop if you want a random number every loop iteration

code:

```
import random
random.seed()

x = random.randrange(3, 65)
h = 1000

while True:
    #put x = random.randrange(3, 65) here if you want a random number every loop iteration
    if x > h:
        break
    h = h - x
    print(h)

print('complete')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have *x = random.randrange(3, 65)*  inside while loop and change "h > x" to "if h > x" and do indentation accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

x = random.randrange(3, 65)
h = 1000

while h > x:
    print(h - x)
    h = h-x

print('complete')
```